# Creating all JPanels at program startup vs. creating them only when needed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, loading

As a general rule, should a program with multiple sections create everything at startup or should it wait to create each part when it is actually needed?

My specific case is a Java kiosk-style application that has multiple different sections. Each section is a different JPanel (with different buttons / JTables / JLabels / etc.) that does a specific task. This is an unfinished project that I haven't touched in a while, but I'm going to complete it and I'm looking at the code and trying to refactor what I think I should have done otherwise.

So far, the program is creating every single JPanel at startup, so whenever an user clicks on one of the button that changes which JPanel is shown, it it loaded instantly since it's already created. So far, I don't think it would matter that much performance-wise, but I'd like to know what is standard practice in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ***not*** load all on start up, as it might make start up slow and also some panels are loaded which are not required. For example you have 4 panels loaded contact, about, pics, and feeds. Suppose you load all 4 at start up, what if user just visited only 2 of them and then close the application. Sometimes it is possible that user wants see only one panel but he has to wait for all panels to load at start up. So I will suggest to load panels as they are required. Load only primary data on frame, and then when user clicks on a button for first time which loads a panel, show a progress bar until that panel is loaded, and from the next time he clicks on button just display the panel with out waiting as it is loaded already by first click.

If your application is getting data from internet then loading all data on start up will also cost extra band width and data charges.

Comment: Good advice, but I don't think the application is going to be opened / closed often. I'll keep the loading bar idea, though, as I know some panels will be used a lot more often than other. Thanks!

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to say, load only those panels that are most likely to be viewed by a user on start up and load others as required. Or else it can make user think "*Why is this thing loading data which are not required?*"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you project need.

If ***response time*** is important for end user , then your  approach is correct.

else create the jpanel on demand

Comment: It not "important" per se, but I don't want it to take 5-10 seconds to load either. I'll have to think about it a little bit more in depth.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends a lot on how much it costs to create that `JPanel`. If it contains a `JTable` with a lot of information that it receives, for example, from a MySQL server over the network, then the cost of creating that `JPanel` is quite big.

In this case, I would create it only when it is needed. Maybe that `JPanel` is never needed while the program is running, so why spend all that time and resources creating it ?

Comment: The cost for most JPanels so far isn't too big, but it might become a problem in the future. There's one of the panels that is pretty close to what you mentioned in your example: when the JPanel is loaded, the user can select some options and then click a button to populate a JTable (for the moment, it gets its data from a local SQLite database, but I'm planning on switching to a MySQL database over the network). So the JPanel isn't too demanding since the processing is only done after the user clicks a button. I'll keep your advice in mind for some other JPanels I have, though. Thanks!